# Include a controller view in another controller view

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

Im using Yii framwork, I have two models (Forum and Topic) wich every forum can have many topics.

Now I want to display all forum's topics in the view of my forum (view.php), after searching on web I found this instruction:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial("/topic/index",array('dataProvider' => new Topic)); ?>
```

But when i'm trying to display forum view i have this error:

> Forum and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getData".

Some help please.

Forgive my bad english.

Comment: Can you post your view code please?

Comment: I use  the standard view generated by CRUD generator  (file: views/forum/view.php), but on the bottom of the file I added my instruction: <?php $this->renderPartial("/topic/index",array('dataProvider' => new Topic)); ?>

Comment: [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) requires an instance of [`CDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) and not of `CActiveRecord`. You need to understand what these are before StackOverflow can help you.

Comment: Mohamed khelifi, kindly post your index.php code?

Answer (score 0):

protected/views/forum/index.php

```
<?php 
/* @var $this ForumController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Forums',
 );
 echo $this->renderPartial('_menu');?>

 <h1>Forums</h1>

  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
  )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because $dataProvider in your example is a Model Object, not a CActiveDataProvider. If you've created your Topic Model with Gii, you'll see there's a search() method in the Model class. This search() method returns a CActiveDataProvider() - which is what you need to use for your CListView:

Try this:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->search(), // Added search()
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```